# Как сохранить/считать файл с помощью JFileChooser?

Tags: java

Приветствую всех,помогите тупеню сообразить как сохранить/считать файл,это учебное задание,где в программе бит бокса нужно реализовать это действие,никак я не могу связать все в кучу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Представлены 2 класса,которые отвечают за сохранение и чтение.

```
public class MySendListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){

        boolean [] checkboxState = new boolean[256];

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){

            JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(i);
            if (check.isSelected()){
                checkboxState[i] = true;
            }
        }
            JFileChooser filesave = new JFileChooser();
            int ret = filesave.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION);

        }
    }
public class MyReadInListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){


        JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
        int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Open File");
        if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(i);
            if (checkboxState[i]){
                check.setSelected(true);
            }else{
                check.setSelected();
            }
            }
        sequencer.stop();
        buildTrackAndStart();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

JFileChooser не читает файл и не пишет в него. Этот класс только показывает пользователю окно выбора файла и возвращает имя (имена) выбранных файлов. Для чтения/записи файла используйте файловые потоки. См. [Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

Comment: спасибо,попробую разобраться

Answer (score 2):

Для сохранения:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();  
if (fc.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {  
    try {  
        FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(fc.getSelectedFile());  
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);  
        os.writeObject(что хотите сохранить);  
    }  
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Что-то пошло не так...");
    }  
}
```

Для считывания - по аналогии (не сильно сложно).

Comment: У нас тут ответы-ссылки не приветствуются. Вам стоит изложить основную часть логики ответа _прямо в ответе_.

Comment: Скорее всего вы попали сюда из-за книги "Изучем Java", тогда просто внимательнее изучите информацию на страницах 481 и 487:)

Comment: Ну, точные номера страниц сильно зависят от конкретного издания.

Comment: у меня 2 издание 2015 года.

Comment: Угу, но это вряд ли поможет тем, у кого другое издание. Вы бы лучше сослались на главу или раздел.

Comment: Если быть совсем точным, то это глава 14. Сохранение объектов

Answer (score 1):

Вот это вроде работает, хотя, думаю, уже не актуально. :-)

```
    public class mySendListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
        boolean[]checkBoxState = new boolean[256];
        for(int i= 0; i<256; i++){
            JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(i);
            if(check.isSelected()){
                checkBoxState[i] = true;
            }
        }
        try{
            JFileChooser filechoo =  new JFileChooser();
            int ret = filechoo.showSaveDialog(null);
            File file = null;
            if(ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            file = filechoo.getSelectedFile();
            } else{
                file = new File("Serialize.ser");
            }
            FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
            os.writeObject(checkBoxState);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public class myReadListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
        boolean[] checkBoxState = null;
        try{
            JFileChooser filechoo =  new JFileChooser();
            File file = null;
            int ret = filechoo.showDialog(null,"Open file");
            if(ret==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                file = filechoo.getSelectedFile();
            }else{
                file = new File("Serialize.ser");
            }
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            checkBoxState  = (boolean[]) is.readObject();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<256; i++){
            JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(i);
            if(checkBoxState[i]){
                check.setSelected(true);
            } else{
                check.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
```